# how can i break a multidimensional array into keys and values

Tags: php, arrays

I really have no clue to achieve the outpu i want. I tried adding these brackets [] next to my key but it made the array more complex 
this is how my array look like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [white] => 1
                    [black] => 1

                )

        )

)
```

this is what i would like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => white
                    [1] => 1

                )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => black
                [1] => 1

            )

        )

)
```

Comment: out of interest why would you like an array within an array, within an array?

Comment: Your second array is impossible. You have two elements with the same key.

Comment: try array_chunk [manual and examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Have you checked out the PHP man page for arrays? http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php.  Specifically array_keys, or array_search

Comment: sorry the second array key should be 1. i want my array like that because i want to use that data in a chart and the chart im using requires data to be multidimensional. You can help me in a straight forward array then i will just convert the array to multidimensional

Comment: You really should simplify the problem. The outermost layer of array with only one element in both examples serves no function in this question at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
$arr = [[['white' => 1, 'black' => 1]]];

$items = $arr[0][0];
$arr[0] = [];
foreach ($items as $k => $v) {
    $arr[0][] = [$k, $v];
}

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => white
                    [1] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => black
                    [1] => 1
                )
        )
)
```